# Animation of a span-tag inside an li-tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a new effect for a link to hover on. I've got the idea ready, but can't get the animation done. Here is a sketch:

[image]

- The ***red*** border shows the whole item, which will probably have
  to be a list item.
- The ***yellow*** borders indicate two separated items. The **right
  yellow bit** will **stay still** there as the left yellow bit moves
  to the left.
- While opening, the ***white*** border should have the word "show" in
  it (which is hidden at the start).

This is how it should need to look in the end:

[image]

Here is a fiddly that reproduces what I mean with a div: 
**http://jsfiddle.net/t5pcjtdo/**

I just can't get it to work with regular text (inside a ul-tag and a li-tag).
Basically it'll need to be something like this:

```
<li>
    <span>.about(</span>
    <span class="hidden">show</span>
    <span>)</span>
</li>
```

AND, how the hell do I make sure the right bracket stands still, while the rest moves to the left?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box-left">.about(</div>
        <div class="box-middle">show</div>
        <div class="box-right">)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    Hover over the red
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var middle = $('.box-middle');
middle.css("width", "0");

$('.wrapper')
    .mouseenter(function () {
    $(middle).animate({
        width: '60px'
    });
})
    .mouseleave(function () {
    $(middle).animate({
        width: '0'
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.wrapper > div {
    float:left;
    height: 35px;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:1px;
    font-size:24px
}

.box-left {
    width:80px;
}

.box-right {
    width: 20px;
}

.box-left, .box-right {
    background-color:red;
}

.box-middle {
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
    width:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

.text{
 clear:left;   
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the effort but can't get where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/t5pcjtdo/8/

When it comes to preventing the right bracket from moving, you want to move the *left side* instead of the middle. Check out the example above to better understand it.

When it comes to CSS, it's just a matter of changing `ul`, `li`, `span` to have the same default CSS properties of a `div`.

If we make `.container` a `ul` instead of `div`, we don't need to change anything.

If we make `.wrapper` a `ul`, we have to do this:

```
.wrapper {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

If we make `box-left`, `box-middle`, and `box-right` spans we need to do this (and remove the whites pace).

```
.box-left, .box-middle, .box-right {
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

As an extra bonus, here's an example with multiple `li` elements, and spacing based on `.box-middle` in each `li`: http://jsfiddle.net/t5pcjtdo/10/

**EDIT**

IE decided to do what it does best (screw up). Need to add this to the CSS to make it work in IE.

```
.box-left {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go! The tricky bit was the display:inline-block for me. It kept messing everything up, but seems like you sorted it out!

Comment: Glad you like my solution. I did notice a nasty little bug with IE though, I fixed it. Check out my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below will automatically handle the following HTML, so you don't need to add the extra elements.

```
<ul>
  <li>.about(show)
  <li>.projects(show)
  <li>.contact(show)
</ul>
```

It also automatically spaces the items, so they won't cover each other up, and you don't need to hard-code the widths.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  var w1= $(this).width();
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\((.+)\)/,'(<span>$1</span>)'));
  var w2= $(this).width();
  $(this).css({
    marginRight: (w1-w2)+5
  });
});

$('li').mouseenter(function() {
  var sp= $(this).find('span');
  sp.css({width:'auto'});
  var width= sp[0].clientWidth;
  sp.css({
    width: 0
  });
  sp.animate({
    width: width
  });
  $(this).animate({
    marginLeft: -width
  });
}).mouseleave(function() {
  var sp= $(this).find('span');
  sp.animate({
    width: 0
  });
  $(this).animate({
    marginLeft: 0
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font: 18px verdana;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

li span {
  width: 1px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>.about(show)
  <li>.projects(show)
  <li>.contact(show)
</ul>
```

Comment: Although the html markup looks remarkable clean, it'll be easier to apply css to the word "show" and the rest when it's divided in 3 spans in the html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks little wierd, but i hope that is what you want

**DEMO** - http://jsfiddle.net/t5pcjtdo/9/

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="box-right">)</div>
         <div class="box-middle">show</div>
        <div class="box-left">.about(</div>

    </div>
    <div class="text">
    Hover over the red
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {width: 180px; float: left;}

.wrapper > div {

    height: 35px;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:1px;
    font-size:24px;

}
.box-left {
    width:80px;
    float: right;
}
.box-right {
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
}
.box-left, .box-right {
    background-color:red;
}
.box-middle {
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: right;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    background-color:pink;
}

.text{
 clear:left;   
}
```